# How to add/append the object type to dictionary value pair of Dictionary<key, Object>?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

`Object` holds global data.

Now i want to add another `Object` of same type of `Dictionary` Value.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit the question appropriately.

Comment: Please add some code or more information of what you exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have another `Dictionary<string, Object>` in an `Object` variable and you want to merge its contents into the original dictionary.

`Dictionary` doesn't have any bulk inserts, except on creation, so your best option is simply:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> pair in (Dictionary<string, Object>)anotherDictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```